# How to Remove wordpress Featured Image on Posts

Tags: wordpress, reference, custom-post-type, wordpress-featured-image

I am using the Hueman wordpress theme in my home. I want to show the featured image on the post but I don't want to that image in a single post.

Can anyone help with this? Here is the [link](http://aftereffectstemplatesfreedownload.com/broadcast-package-effects-templates-free-download-2/)

Comment: Why don't you ask on the support forum? Check your single.php file and search for the container where the image is and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to customize single post detail page.
So, go to single.php.
Usally this file is located in your theme path that is as below.

```
www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/
```

Go to above path and open single.php. In that remove below code 
 `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` and replace it with

```
 the_title();    //For Post Title 
 the_content();  //For Content of the post
```

If you want to add image use 
`the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail');`